# Is it possible to sync google contacts for birth-dates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, contacts

In this code I only fetch name and email. Is it possible to fetch also the birthday of all contacts when I sync contact using Google feed URL in database? I am not able to fetch the contact with the birthday only able to fetch the name and email.

```
$return[] = array (
                'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
                'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
                'image' => $image,

            );
```

Comment: _enter image description herein above code i am only fetch name and email is possible fetch also birthday of the all contacts when i sync contact using google feed `_ If your english isn't well please ask a friend to review your text.

Comment: thank you for edit

Comment: What's the structure of `$contact`?